# file.width e file.height - Não funciona no Dropzone.js

Tags: jquery, dropzonejs

Estou implementado o sistema de Dropzone.js em um sistema, porem, preciso limitar o tamanho da imagem.
Como pego estas informações para limitar o upload que não esteja dentro dos padrões?

```js
    
    
 Dropzone.options.dropzoneFrom = {
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  acceptedFiles:".jpg, .jpeg",
                maxFilesize: 1, 
  maxFiles:3,
  addRemoveLinks:true,
                dictFileTooBig: "Imagem supera o tamanho permitido ({{filesize}}Mb). Tamanho maximo: {{maxFilesize}}Mb.",
                  createImageThumbnails: false,
                accept: function(file, done) {
                console.log(file.width)    
                if (file.name === "teste.jpg") {
                  done("Naha, you don't.");
                }
                    else { done(); }
                },
                
               
                
                
  init: function(){
   var submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit-all');
   myDropzone = this;
   submitButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
    myDropzone.processQueue();
   });
   /*this.on("complete",function() {
    if(this.getQueuedFiles().length == 0 && this.getUploadingFiles().length == 0)
    {
     var _this = this;
     _this.removeAllFiles();
    }
   });*/
  },
 };
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>     
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/dropzone.css"/>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/dropzone.js"></script>
  
  
  <div class="container">
   <br/>
   <h3 align="center">Upload de arquivo</h3>
   <br/>
   
   <form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneFrom" style="  border: 2px dashed rgb(54, 183, 0);">
   </form>
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <div align="center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="submit-all"> Upload</button>
   </div>
    
   <br/>
   <br/>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As propriedades `file.width` e `file.height` não existem no Dropzone. Basta você fazer um `console.log(file)` e verá que elas não existem, apenas o `file.name` e outras (como o peso em bytes), mas não o `.width` e o `.height`.

Use a `APIFileReader()` para pegar as dimensões da imagem. Coloque na função do `accept:`

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (function(entry) {
   var image = new Image(); 
   image.src = entry.target.result;
   image.onload = function() {
      console.log(this.width); // mostra o width
      console.log(this.height); // mostra o height
   };
});
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Só que, como a função do `.onload` é assíncrona, você terá que fazer os devidos tratamentos dentro dela.

Comment: Blz, obrigado, vou tentar implantar aqui e ver o resultado

Comment: Veja aí e qualquer coisa pode me chamar aqui.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado pela ajuda!!!